# Unit Testing where return is not a single parameter

Tags: c#, winforms, unit-testing, tdd

I'm not sure how I would unit test something in which the return is returned as a a collective string rather than one item.

For example, my code

```
Customer newCustomer = new Customer(
  Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text), txtOne.Text, txtTwo.Text, txtThree.Text, 
  txtFour.Text, txtFive.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtSix.Text));
return newCustomer;
```

returns from another form the entry

```
-       newCustomer {dsadasd, kgkjhk, khkjhkh, kjhkhk , kjhkh} 

CastleBlackArmoury.Customer
        Address1    "kgkjhk"    string
        Address2    "khkjhkh"   string
        Age 98  int
        ID  4   int
        Name    "dsadasd"   string
        Postcode    "kjhkh" string
        Town    "kjhkhk"    string
```

I'm trying to test if the method then accepts the values provided (ID is auto generated and placed in a locked out text box, and Age is validated using a KeyPress event on the `txtSix.txt` textbox).

Comment: This should drive you to implement `equals` for the class in question - then you can assert that your actual customer is equal to the expected one, and it's still just a single comparison.

Comment: Side note: Please avoid extra stories of your life in posts on SO and long "thank you"/"new here" text. Also try to format your code without horizontal scroll if possible.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Without being to blunt, I was just trying to be nice. Thankyou for formatting my post however, im still finding my feet around here.

Comment: You show respect by minimizing amount of text not related to your actual problem - feel free to check out discussion on [meta - hi and thanks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/2960).

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `Equals` in `Customer` *solely* for the purposes of a test is a **Test Smell**: it's *test logic in production* and has been given the name [**Equality Pollution**](http://xunitpatterns.com/Test%20Logic%20in%20Production.html) by Gerard Meszaros in [XUnit Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/). He points out the potential impact of this:

> Equality Pollution may make it difficult to introduce the `equals` logic prescribed by some new requirement if it already exists to support test-specific equality for another test.

We've added a form of potentially harmful coupling. Instead, we should consider implementing [test-specific equality](http://xunitpatterns.com/test-specific%20equality.html) with [custom assertions](http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html). These can be as simple as several asserts in a helper method. Alternatively, you may want to consider using [SemanticComparison](http://www.nuget.org/packages/SemanticComparison) which is a stand-alone component of the [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture) framework and handles much of the comparison of two objects for you.

If you can't create custom assertions because the values in `Customer` are private, your tests may be telling you one of two things: that they belong to the public API of the class, or that you shouldn't be testing their specific values as they are private implementation details that should remain encapsulated. You'll be in a better position to know which is the case in the context of the class and its intended usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can either implement `Equals` for you `Customer` type (if it is indeed "value" type in the same sense the `string is "value" type). Or you can compare fields you expect to be set to correct values.

I.e. if you particular test checks if `MethodToTest` sets some particular `Postcode` you'd write something like:

```
public void MethodToTest_SetsWellKnownPostcode_ByDefault()
{
  var expectedPostCode = "somePostCode";
  Customer actual = MethodToTest();

  Assert.Equals(expectedPostCode, actual.Postcode);
}
```